# Importing a library from apache website

Tags: java, android, apache, http

I am trying to familiarize myself with the Apache HttpClient by using [Vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html#httpclient).

The first paragraph explains how I have to use a library to download the binaries with dependencies from hc.apache.org, then add them to my project class path. My question is that im having trouble doing so successfully.

When I go to the apache site and [download the binaries](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi), the file extensions types are `.tar.gz`.  Shouldn't they be .jar?  Can somebody please help clarify this for me Thank You!

Comment: apache http client is already part of android, you don't need to import that. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open it with zipping prog and have a look into the lib folder

Comment: When i run the code i get a class cast exception, could this mean i imported the libaries wrong? i went to properties, java build path then i just imported all the libraries(6 of them) through pushing the add external jars button.

Comment: Have a look at zapl's comment. My fault. He is absolutely right. If there is no need for you to have the latest release you do not need to include the libs by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Android already includes this library, so you don't have to do anything special.

You may want to follow an Android tutorial though.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html

Comment: So in other words i dont have to go by the first paragraph in his post? 
"
The Apache HttpClient library simplifies handling HTTP requests. To use this library download the binaries with dependencies from http://hc.apache.org/ and add then to your project class path. Apache HttpClient is widely used for example it is included in the Android Platform.
"

Comment: I dont have to download the binaries?

Comment: No, you don't have to download the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

The tarfile (there are zip files too) is just a compressed folder with the `.jar` files in it.

Unzip (or un-tar) the file and copy all of the `.jar` files into the `libs/` folder for your application. Android will automatically include them in your built app.